# Getting issue to Individual TableView cell is not update after content load

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

In tableview cell added one WKWebView after load HTML data tableView cell height is not updated, I have tried below code

```
// redraw the tableView
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WKWebView` has no intrinsic content size which means it doesn't create its height according to content inside it , you need to give it a static height or change `heightForRowAt` of the `tableView`